# How to get the ID of the last insert

Tags: php

I have an application and around 20 accounts are created per minute (on average). I need to implement a new feature which requires the ID of the last insert.

I am using PDO.

The question is, lets say 5 users create accounts at exactly the same time. Will it return the ID from the database for that users profile that was just created, or will it return the last insert?

If you get what I mean.

Comment: Won't the most recent insert be for the user that was most recently created?

Comment: If you are using MySQL then look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: URLs are formatted like this: site.com/3023/andy-mickell

The 3023 is the A_I key, and andy-mickell is the user. This allows for duplicate names. Just incase people have the same name.

So when the profile is created, I want to redirect them to their new profile. For this I need to know the primary key of that record. I.e create the record, get the primary key, and forward them to the profile.

Answer (score 3):

> Will it return the ID from the database for that users profile that was just created, or will it return the last insert?

It will return the last insert id of the current connection session. So even if a new record is created in another instance of the same script, the last insert id will be the one you want.

Example (in psuedo-event form):

> Create new user // with id of 5
>
> Sleep for 10 seconds - meanwhile another script inserts 3 users
>
> Fetch the last insert id - this will be 5

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the PDO::lastInsertID function: http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: I have looked at this but people are having so many issues with it.

Comment: I use the MySQLi Class and its insert_id (http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) function and I never had any problem. As the function works per connection you make through php it will always return the correct id for a user (as long as you execute it in the same script).

Comment: You can always run a second query getting the new ID using the user data in the WHERE clause if you don't trust the lastInsertId function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL (I don´t think all databases have a last-insert ID functionality like MySQL...), every script will return the ID for the item it has just entered, all instances operate independently.

Comment: I use `lastInsertId()`, never had any problems with it.